# Accessing a file in another server from GWT Client side

Tags: ajax, gwt, same-origin-policy

I have a file, `sample.xml` located at one web server. I want to access this file from a GWT application running at another server. I dont want to make RPC calls to the same server serving GWT application and access the required file on server side (like a proxy). I want to access the file directly from client side as my application is going to be hosted as static files in a web server.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you have some control over that server? If you do, JSONP would work. Otherwise... I don't see any elegant way - the SOP is there for a reason ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sure - you must issue a XHR (XmlHTTPRequest) from the browser, and then parse the data.
In GWT you can do it using the `RequestBuilder` class (see [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html)).

Please note that some client side restrictions may apply (e.g. Single Origin Policy etc.)

You issue the request (GET or POST - GET in your case) and pass a callback instance.
The instance's `onResponseReceived` method receives a `Response` object, which by calling its `getText` method returns the received contents.

Comment: the 'RequestBuilder' helped. But my requirement is to access a file from another server than the one from which the application code is served. I am getting com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestPermissionException stating same orgin policy restriction.

Comment: If you have access to the file server, you could ease the SOP restrictions by sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header - but it should be used carefully as it does impose some risk.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to have your website (`a.com/index.html`) reference `b.com/sample.xml`. I see a few options.

If you have access to `b.com`'s servers:

- Edit `sample.xml` into `sample.js` to contain the same information in JSON with a callback, and reference it with a `script` tag
- Compile your website using the cross-site loader (see [Controlling Compiler Output](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml)), put your `index.html` at `b.com/index.html`, put all the rest of your files on `a.com`. Then all your RPC calls can go to `b.com`, but this means the user would have to navigate to `b.com` instead of `a.com`

If you don't have access to `b.com`'s servers:
 - Simply provide a link for people to download `sample.xml`
 - Host `a.com` on a server with some kind of script support (PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, anything) and put a proxy to `b.com/sample.xml`